# JSONP Callback variable hoisting, scoping anomoly

Tags: jquery, callback, scope, jsonp, hoisting

I have a global array I want to populate with URLs to JPEGs at Flickr. I intend to pass this array around between functions.

When I try to read the contents of the array (or console.log from main.js:40) from within my JASONP callback function it appears to be empty. Yet from the browser console it seems fine (screen shot).  My JASONP callback seems able to `array.push()` but can't read `array[i].src`.

What's going on here?

[image: screenshot of console]

I seem to be misunderstanding how variables are scoped from JASONP callbacks. Can someone enlighten me (in super-noob laymen's terms) as to what's happening here and show me what this should look like?

JSFiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/Nyquist212/7gtxetxj/

```
function UrlExists(url, callback) {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', url);
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == this.DONE) {
            callback(this.status = 200);
        }
    };
    http.send();
};

var images = []; // Store imgs in here

$.getJSON("https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&jsoncallback=?",
      { 
          api_key : "da2015d88b5eab3b3d7d989c13c4d430",
          content_type : 1,
          text : "landscape, beach, coast, surf, black, white",
          format : "json",
          per_page : 10
      },

      function jsonFlickrApi (results) { // my JSONP callback func 

            for (var i=0; i < results.photos.photo.length; i++) {
                var farm    = results.photos.photo[i].farm;
                var id      = results.photos.photo[i].id;
                var server  = results.photos.photo[i].server;
                var secret  = results.photos.photo[i].secret;
                var furl    = "https://farm" + farm + ".staticflickr.com/" + server + "/" + id + "_" + secret + "_m" + ".jpg";

                if (!UrlExists(furl, mycallback)) {
                    function mycallback(results){
                        images.push({"src":furl}); 
                        };
                    $("<img />").attr("src", furl).appendTo("#one");              // This works...
                    //$("<img />").attr("src", images[i].src).appendTo("#one");   // Why wont this work?
                }; 
            }; // End for 

            console.log(images); // Returns empty!?!

      } // End jsonFlickrApi
); // End getJSON
```

Thank you.

Comment: I'm trying to test the Header of the GET request to see if it's a valid URL. i.e. return a status of "200"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
if (!UrlExists(furl, mycallback)) {
    function mycallback(results) {
        images.push({
            "src": furl
        });
    };
    $("<img />").attr("src", furl).appendTo("#one"); // This works...
    //$("<img />").attr("src", images[i].src).appendTo("#one");   // Why wont this work?
};
```

never **calls** that `mycallback` function, and thus nothing is ever added to `images`. (Also note that you don't put `;` after the closing `}` of the block attached to a constrol flow statement like `if`.)

Assuming `UrlExists` expects you to pass it a callback for some reason and calls that callback asynchronously, you'll need to actually pass the function to it, and you'll need to ensure that when the function is called, it's called with the right `furl` (since if it's called asynchronous, the `furl` you're currently using will have been changed before the callback is called). The same would be true of `i` in your commented out code. With those assumptions in place, you can do this:

```
function jsonFlickrApi(results) { // my JSONP callback func 

    results.photos.photo.forEach(function(photo) {
        var furl = "https://farm" + photo.farm +
                   ".staticflickr.com/" +
                   photo.server + "/" +
                   photo.id + "_" +
                   photo.secret + "_m" + ".jpg";
        UrlExists(furl, function() {  // I assume this is called if the URL does exist, and that that's what you want 
            images.push({
                "src": furl
            });
            $("<img />").attr("src", furl).appendTo("#one");
        });
    });

    // Note that `images` will still be empty here, waiting for the callbacks
    // from UrlExists

} // End jsonFlickrApi
```

Now, nothing in the `UrlExists` callback is relying on something that will change before the callback occurs, because a new, separate `furl` is created for every call to the `forEach` callback.

Comment: Sounds like I'm over complicating things(?). `UrlExists` is supposed to return `true` before `images.push()` puts the URL into the array `images[]`. If it returns `false` I want to ignore or drop the URL. I guess I'm still confused why I can't address `images[i].src` from withing the `jsonFlickrApi` callback but I can from the browsers console.

Comment: @ColinA.White: It's a timing thing. In your current code, you're trying to use `images` before it has anything in it. But the above should fix that, if you make `UrlExists` call the callback if the URL exists (or modify it so it passes a `true`/`false` result to the callback, and then the callback does what's necessary).

Comment: Your code allows me to read `images[i]src` from within the `jsonFlickApi` callback function. http://jsfiddle.net/Nyquist212/7gtxetxj/5/ but how do I deal with the async nature if I want to pass a populated `images[]` to other functions?

Comment: @ColinA.White: You have your function that all this logic contains either: 1) Accept a callback it calls when it has all the images, or 2) Return a promise it fulfills when it has all the images.

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful.